# Kotlin, Android Studio. "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match" on Text(...)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, overloading, ambiguity

I've recently started to learn app development in Android Studio and Kotlin so I am a total beginner but I learn fast. However, I stumbled on this error: "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match". I have only one file MainActivity.kt in which I defined 2 Composable functions ItemOrder and UpperPanel. The problem is when I try to call Text(...) function in both of these 2. I don`t know why the error appears and searched online but none of the related answers really solved my problem. I repeat I am a beginner so I might do a rookie mistake somewhere. I attach a snippet of the error below.
[image]

I also have to mention that I import only this Text instance : "import androidx.compose.material3.Text" so to my bigger surprise I don't understand how the conflict appears even though I have only one import in a single file. Thanks to everyone in advance.

P.S.: I can also attach the code if necessary but I thought I could save space.

P.S.S.: I've just noticed that the previews are ok if I change the value of one parameter of a Text(...) constructor, even though the actual Text word is underlined with red giving the error I've just shown. So I think I can continue to code, but I am still wondering what the problem is or, if the case, how to disable the red underlines.

Later update: I managed to  get rid of the red underlines of the Text constructor by specifying the onTextLayout, even if empty, in the parameter list. However, now the problem is at runtime when I try to run the app. As Beto Caldas suggested, it is indeed a problem related to duplicated classes found and even though I can't see it directly by inspecting the list of imports (I have only one file) after further digging I opened the Navigate -> Class window and found out it is about the coexistence of the packages he mentioned. But, for the moment, I don't know how to eliminate the second.

Problem solved. I looked into the gradle scripts and removed the second import in Beto Caldas' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have those both imports

```
{ group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
```

and

```
{ group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3-android", version.ref = "material3Android" }
```

Remove the second.

Are you reading compose documentation and created a new project to test it?
If so, you will have a problem with documentation cuz the documentation was done with Material 2 as target and your new project is targeting Material 3.
This migration document can help https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3

Comment: After further digging into the problem I found out I somehow have these 2 packages in the project, but I didn't explicitly add them by hand, or at least not intentionally. I realised I have both of them after looking into the Navigate -> Class window. The only thing I can think of right now is that I imported the first one explicitly and then the second one is imported implicitly by another import or something like that. To sum up for the moment I have a bit of a hard time in finding out how to remove the second.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem. I looked into the gradle scripts. There are 2, build.gradle.kts for project level and for app level. And I removed the second import from there thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell because of the ... thing at the end, but if my memory serves me right the problem is as follows:

You can overload a function in a way that the expected parameter list is different. For example you can have a `Blah(text: String, text2: String)` and a `Blah(text: String, foo: Int)`. Then the parameters presented at the call site will make it clear which function is to be called:
`Blah("foo", "bar")` or `Blah("something", 5)`. However, if you don't supply enough parameters (because most of them are optional in your case) and try to call the function with one String param, this ambiguity can not be resolved (`Blah("bar")`). I suggest you check these functions at the source and read through the param list carefully. Figure out the difference and change your call to make it clear which one is to be called. I know it sounds a bit like "go have a look and figure it out" . :D There will be some difference in the param list, that is the key.

Comment: I understand what you say and I think the principle is correct. However, I assure you, and hopefully I'm not wrong, that the only difference between the 2 function prototypes is about the OnTextLayout parameter. 
 onTextLayout: ((TextLayoutResult) → Unit)? = ...  |||
onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ...
And for the moment I don't see the difference even though I see there is one extra question mark in the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your hints partially solved the problem.